# AVAudioPlayer issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Actually I am using `AVAudioPlayer`.
my player is working very fine (forward,revind,play,pause,volume,progress bar).
Only problem is that I am not able to stop the song.
so all songs are overlapped please any body tell me where I put `[self.player stop]` to stop my player when I play new song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain your player object, and then call player stop before you start another track.  Its difficult to tell from your question, but are you actually trying to queue up a number of songs ?